# KDevelop4: Error while loading shared libraries

Tags: c, linker, cmake, kdevelop4

I am trying to use the Intel MKL libraries for the first time. I am using CMake to build a simple project in which MKL is used. I work in the KDevelop 4.6 environment.

The project is built and installed without errors. Linking the libraries is thus succesful. While executing within KDevelop, I get the following error:

`Error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_intel_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The CMakeLists file looks essentially as follows:

```
project(testmkl)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

enable_language(Fortran)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=c99 -Wall -lpthread") 
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

# MKL
find_package(MKL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${MKL_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package(M REQUIRED)
include_directories(${M_INCLUDES})

add_executable(testmkl ./main.c)
target_link_libraries(testmkl ${M_LIBRARIES} ${MKL_BLAS} ${MKL_LAPACK} ${MKL_INTEL} ${MKL_SEQUENTIAL} ${MKL_CORE})
install(TARGETS testmkl DESTINATION .)
```

`libmkl_intel_lp64.so` is found in the first folder of the `LP_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, so I wouldn't expect any error during the execution. Actually, when running the program from the command window, everything seems to work fine.

The ldd output for the executable is:

```
>> ldd ./testmkl
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff951fe000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003061a00000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003061200000)
libmkl_intel_lp64.so => /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so (0x00007f6f65ef6000)
libmkl_sequential.so => /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.so (0x00007f6f65846000)
libmkl_core.so => /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so (0x00007f6f64317000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003060e00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003060600000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003061600000)
```

The linked libraries are thus correctly found. Why won't the program work in the KDevelop environment?

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: My guess would be that KDevelop has a different environment, I don't have it in-front of me so you should just poke around some options and see if it overrides something. Or if you changed `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` recently enough that your session where KDevelop was started does not reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one short question: are you excuting your program from a terminal or trying to execute from KDE gui (e.g. by double-click)?

On many linux OS, now LD_LIBRARY_PATH is deprecated. LD finds the dependencies thanks to what is listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` . You may have to add a script somewhere there to include your libraries. In fact you just have to add the path to your libraries in those scripts.

example from `/etc/ld.so.conf/libc.conf`:

```
# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib
```

This may work for you.

edit:
you shoud also run `ldconfig` to update the LD database and/or use `ldconfig -v`, which does the same but with extended output

edit2: `ldconfig` may require root privileges to be understood by the GUI

Comment: Thanks Danduk82, I added the folder in which the `libmkl_intel_lp64.so` was situated according to `ldd` in a new .conf file in the `etc/ld.so.conf/` folder, run `ldconfig -v` and that worked for me. Didn't know that the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is deprecated...
I cannot vote up because I don't have enough reputation yet, sorry for this!

Comment: great, maybe you could accept the answer to close the thread ;) cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and now it solved through configuration of environment variable in kdevelop.

1. Go to project->open configuration
2. Select make tab
3. Click setting icon in Active environment profile bar and add your environment variable:

   ```
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /your/shared/library/path
   ```