# How to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Jenkins

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I am having java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError problem while running a job from Jenkins.

```
 <error message="no JSTAF in java.library.path" type="java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError">java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JSTAF in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1681)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
```

Basically I need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and when this is set, it works fine from command line execution. For example, when I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` like following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=</proj/lib>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Upon setting, the code execution works fine from command line.

I have tried to set this `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` using the `EnvInjectPlugin` and injected the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Still I am not sure why Jenkins is not picking up this `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. How to set this up so that Jenkins job execution will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted an answer to a similar question yesterday here: [KDevelop4: Error while loading shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409558/kdevelop4-error-while-loading-shared-libraries/21418289#21418289)

In practice, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is deprecated in many Linux OS. Use config files in /etc/ld.so.conf.d for that and run `ldconfig` before starting Jenkins. (see the above cited post)

EDIT [solution]:

after having discussed it in chat, the problem has been solved by adding :

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LYBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:<myPathForJenkins>
```

in a short script in */etc/profile.d/* and setting it executable with `chmod +x`

Comment: It is not clear to me where to add reference to my </proj/lib>. I dont see /etc/ld.so.conf/libc.conf in my system.

Comment: what OS are you running?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)

Comment: There should be a file called `/etc/ld.so.conf` and a directory called `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` ... Isn't it?

Comment: So looks like I need to create a file under /etc/ld.so.conf.d.

Comment: Ok, then simply look at one *.conf* file in the */etc/ld.so.conf.d* directory and do one similar for your application, for example : `echo <my/lib/dir> > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/myConfFile.conf` . In the script, you simply must add the path to your libs.

Comment: And then just run `ldconfig` before restarting your application.

Comment: ok. will restart Jenkins and will run the job to see whether the problem persists or not.

Comment: Previously I used to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I presume from now on even to run from command line I do not need to export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46381/discussion-between-baishakh-and-danduk82)