# Why is the version of sqlite different for different users on my jenkins server?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, jenkins

As the jenkins user, my `sqlite_version` is `3.7.17`

```
bash-4.2$ python3.8
Python 3.8.2 (default, May  8 2020, 12:44:28) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3 
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.7.17'
```

as my root user the `sqlite_version` is `3.31.1`

```
[root@jenkins ~]# python3.8
Python 3.8.2 (default, May  8 2020, 12:44:28) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.31.1'
```

They are both using the same python binary

```
[root@jenkins ~]# which python3.8
/usr/local/bin/python3.8

bash-4.2$ which python3.8
/usr/local/bin/python3.8
```

Steps I took after installing new sqlite3 from source:

- Deleted the old version of `sqlite3` in `/bin`
- I added `/usr/local/bin` to the `jenkins` path in `/var/lib/jenkins/.bashrc`

Do you have any idea how to make the jenkins python use the new sqlite3 version?

**Update:**

Running `sqlite3.__file__`:

*Jenkins*

```
>>> sqlite3.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/__init__.py'
```

*Root*

```
>>> sqlite3.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/__init__.py'
```

Comment: What is the value of `sqlite3.__file__` ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the info. The output of that attribute is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following works for me on CentOS 7.7:

---

**Install Python Dependencies**:

```
sudo yum -y groupinstall 'Development Tools'
sudo yum -y install openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel
```

---

**SQLite source install**:

```
wget https://sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3310100.tar.gz
tar -xf sqlite-autoconf-3310100.tar.gz
cd sqlite-autoconf-3310100/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

---

**Python source install**:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.2/Python-3.8.2.tar.xz
tar -xf Python-3.8.2.tar.xz
cd Python-3.8.2/
sudo LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib make altinstall
```

---

**Test**:

```
[centos@jenkins ~]$ sudo su
[root@jenkins centos]# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
[root@jenkins centos]# grep PATH /root/.bashrc
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
[root@jenkins centos]# python3.8
Python 3.8.2 (default, May 15 2020, 07:26:39)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.31.1'
>>> sqlite3.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/__init__.py'
>>>

[root@jenkins centos]# exit
[centos@jenkins ~]$
[centos@jenkins ~]$ sudo su - jenkins
Last login: Fri May 15 07:44:53 UTC 2020 on pts/0
-bash-4.2$ id
uid=996(jenkins) gid=993(jenkins) groups=993(jenkins) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
-bash-4.2$ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins
-bash-4.2$ grep PATH .bashrc
grep: .bashrc: No such file or directory
-bash-4.2$ python3.8
Python 3.8.2 (default, May 15 2020, 07:26:39)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.31.1'
>>> sqlite3.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/__init__.py'
>>>
```

Comment: Aha, so `LD_RUN_PATH` is used for link time resolution. Where I was using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which specifies runtime resolution of linked libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the `PYTHONPATH` and/or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for both `root` and `jenkins` ?

#### About *Python path* (`PYTHONPATH`)

You can use [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) to print the effective `PYTHONPATH` for each environment. If you see a difference, you are probably using 2 different versions of sqlite3 library.

If it's indeed the issue, you can try to change the `PYTHONPATH` in your `jenkins` recipe.

#### About shared library path (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`/`/etc/ld.so.conf`)

It could also be a wrong PATH for the dynamic loader. Indeed `.so` files could be loaded from different path. To change/see the shared library path, you can refer to the following answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22999

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is one way to configure shared library path but you could also use `/etc/ld.so.conf`. There is an [answer about how to set the library path for Jenkins here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21444427/2437450)

Comment: @surfer190 do you have feedback about my answer ?

Comment: The `sys.path` are the same in both cases. It seems the issue is to do with `ld` the GNU linker. If this is set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`, the correct sqlite3 version is used.

Comment: Hi surfer190. I edited my answer to add few references about shared library path and Jenkins. Hope it helps. Indeed there was not only the _python path_ but also the _shared library path_!
In some cases some users might have also the issue of _python path_  so I let this option in the answer!